# Extending an embedding $:S^1\rightarrow \mathbb R^{n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Assume we have an embedding $f:S^1\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$. I want to extend $f$ to an embedding $\tilde{f}:B\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, where $B$ is the closed unit ball of $\mathbb R^2$. In fact, I want to see $f(S^1)$ as the boundary of a smooth manifold. I would appreciate some ideas on the construction of $\tilde{f}$.

**Edit:** I am thinking of contracting $f$ to a point $w_0\in \mathbb R^n$, let's say through the homotopy $F:S^1\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, with $F(x,1)=f(x)$ and $F(x,0)=w_0$. Now I define $\tilde f(x)=F(\frac{x}{|x|},|x|)$ for $x\in B$. However, how can I make sure that $\tilde{f} (B)$ is a manifold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n=3$ what you want to prove is not true. The only knot which bounds a disk is the unknot. The page about [Seifert surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_surface) at Wikipedia has details.

When $n>3$, you can use the general position theorem stated [here](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/High_codimension_embeddings%3a_classification) to conclude that all $S^1$s in $\mathbb R^n$ are isotopic (smoothly if the knot is smooth) and reduce the problem to the standardly embedded unknot, which is easy.

One should be able to prove this «by hand»: if the knot $K$ is smooth, there is a point $p$ such that the lines through $p$ pass through at most one point of $K$. Indeed, the set $S$ of points on the lines which pass through two points of $K$ is the image of a smooth map $U\to\mathbb R^n$ with $U\subseteq S^1\times S^1\times\mathbb R$ an open set, so $S$ is not all of $\mathbb R^n$: it suffices to pick a $p$ in $\mathbb R^n\setminus S$. Now you can construct a "cone" with vertex at $p$ and base the knot. This is not smooth, but it becomes smooth if you smooth it at the apex.

Comment: If we have an embedding $S^1\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ isn't it the case of the unknot?

Comment: @DimitrisDallas, if $n>3$, then yes, all circles in $\mathbb R^n$ are unknotted. That is exactly why my answer begins with «If $n=3$...»! :-)

Comment: Yes I see, I am trying to understand the concept. Luckily, the construction I have is an unknotted circle so I can do it for $\mathbb R^3$ too.